Random forest regression model for stock price prediction output has a flat line in the predicted values during the initial values
I have a random forest regression model for predicting the close price for stock data. I am getting model accuracy as like this:
/n Best Parameters: {'max_depth': 10, 'min_samples_leaf': 2, 'min_samples_split': 2, 'n_estimators': 50}
Model Accuracy: 0.9836086637624329
Mean Squared Error: 0.0012209441316212947
R-squared (Coefficient of Determination): 0.9836086637624329
I have used GridSearch for best parameters. I want to confirm the model is not  overfit. I have done the below plots:

I am wondering why the residual plot has initial straight line  portion. I will also add the  learning curve and actual v/s predicted. 

Somebody please help me  to understand what causes this inconsistency  in the  model?

It is hard to say without knowing the time of inputs you are providing your model, but apparently based on the learned patterns in the training data most of the days as the start of your test data end up in the same leaf node leading to the same prediction. Additionally, the random forest model can't predict lower values than it has seen in its training set, so it will never be able to predict the closing prices of around 100 that are present in the test data.
